# jspdf increase row height for autotable generated in the script file

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am working on a project that generates table in the javascript file. I want to leave some space between the header and the first row. I can't find a way to do that in jspdf.

Here is the array for autotable:

```
var columns = ["", "", "", "", "", "Custom % Usage"];
    var rows = [
      ["% HSA Used", "40%", "65%", "80%", "100%", customPercent + "%"],
      // ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
      ["HSA $ spend(Single)", "$" +(hsaSingle12).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaSingle2).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaSingle3).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaSingle4).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaSingle5).innerHTML],
      ["HSA $ spend(Family)", "$" +(hsaFamily1).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaFamily2).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaFamily3).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaFamily4).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaFamily5).innerHTML],
      ["HSA Admin Fee", "$" +(hsaAdmin1).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaAdmin2).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaAdmin3).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaAdmin4).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaAdmin5).innerHTML],
      ["Provincial Tax", "$" +(hsaTax1).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaTax2).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaTax3).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaTax4).innerHTML, "$" +(hsaTax5).innerHTML],
      ["Total Annual Cost", "$" +(hsa_totalCost1).innerHTML, "$" +(hsa_totalCost2).innerHTML, "$" +(hsa_totalCost3).innerHTML, "$" +(hsa_totalCost4).innerHTML, "$" +(hsa_totalCost5).innerHTML]
    ];
```

And here I am defining the styles for the table. The columnstyles works perfectly but the rowStyles doesn't work.

```
  doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {

      styles: {
        fontSize: 10,
        font: "helvetica", // helvetica, times, courier
        lineColor: 255,
        // lineColor: [192,192,192],
        lineWidth: 1,
        fontStyle: 'normal', // normal, bold, italic, bolditalic
        overflow: 'ellipsize', // visible, hidden, ellipsize or linebreak
        fillColor: false, // false for transparent or a color as described below
        textColor: 20,
        halign: 'left', // left, center, right
        valign: 'middle', // top, middle, bottom
        columnWidth: 'auto',
      }, // 'auto', 'wrap' or a number


      columnStyles: {
        // 1: {columnWidth: 28, fillColor: [103,129,191], fontStyle: 'bold', textColor: (255,255,255)},
        1: {columnWidth: 28},
        2: {columnWidth: 20},
        3: {columnWidth: 20},
        4: {columnWidth: 20},
        5: {columnWidth: 35},
        columnWidth: 'wrap'
      },

rowStyles: {
        0: {rowHeight: 50}
      },


      margin: {top: 220},
      addPageContent: function(data) {
      }

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
doc.autoTable(columns, arrSign, {
  drawRow : function (row, data) {
  row.height = 80;
},
```